# Samsung RF266 refrigerator not cooling - Fan making noise

Tags: refrigerator

We have a Samsung RF266 refrigerator that has started on make funny noises. More like fan noise. It has something called to twin cooling technology similar this image.

[image]

There is evidence of ice buildup inside the refrigerator particularity around vent holes indicated by the red marking in the picture.

Also recently we have observed some of the food is starting to go bad.

Anything thought on what might be the cause.

Comment: Check these two links http://support-us.samsung.com/cyber/popup/iframe/pop_troubleshooting_fr.jsp?idx=669461&modelname=RF266AARS/XAA&modelcode=RF266AARS/XAA      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0MfViKalAg

Comment: One me good link [troubleshooting](http://www.uncleharrywizard.com/nephewclub/wizardfrig/samsung/samsung---rf265---rf266---4.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

I've had this issue before with Samsung refrigerators.  The sound of the fan is usually it hitting against an ice build-up, which means no air-circulation, which means no cooling.  The best solution to try first is to do a complete defrost (unplug the fridge and leave the doors open for 72 hours, removing any ice build-up that you can see/find).  This worked for my fridge.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy but temporary fix for noise caused by fan blades hitting ice build-up (temporary, since it treats only the symptom of Samsung's flawed design, rather than the cause). You don't need to remove food or even open the fridge: Simultaneously press "Freezer" and "Lighting" on front panel of fridge and hold (8 seconds on my fridge) until it beeps. Release, and press "Freezer" repeatedly (three times for my model) until it displays "rd" (rear defrost). This manually activates the rear defroster, and your fridge will beep annoyingly for awhile (about 27 minutes on my fridge). I usually repeat this process 4-6 times in a row, setting my phone timer for 27 minutes to keep reminding me to go and restart it. This fix usually lasts me a couple of weeks. If you remember to do it frequently, on a preventative basis--say, before going to work or to bed, you may stay ahead of the problem.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve done everything beside blowing this piece of crap up ! Finally I found a solution that has lasted over 6 months . Take everything out of the frig including shelves . Remove plastic fan cover and the lines running to the left of the fan are the ones freezing up bad design on Samsung’s part . Buy some simple insulation tape and wrap all the lines that are freezing . I swear it works finally!

Answer (score 1):

The fan to circulate air is essential in full sized refrigerators.  If the fan has slipped on its shaft or the motor is not spinning at full speed, the cooling coils would get too cold (and form ice), and the rest of the fridge would not cool properly because of the lack of airflow.

I have a similar fridge and I have never heard the fan.  You hearing noises seems to indicate that something is happening to the fan. If that is the problem, its probably going to be one of the cheaper issues you can have - maybe not "cheap", but a lot better than a bad compressor or something.

You might want to stop using it until you can get it fixed because it may be over-working the compressor in its current state.

Answer (score 1):

Turn ice maker off on samsung fridge empty all ice . Let fridge run with icemaker off. Then turn icemaker on and a day latter turn icemaker off. Only turn ice maker back on when you need ice. This will end your icing problem and fan noise issue permanently. Keeping your icemaker off seems to be the best solution to icing and fan noise problem.