# Ice buildup inside Samsung RF266 refrigerator

Tags: refrigerator

Per the suggestion to the question [Samsung RF266 refrigerator not cooling - Fan making noise](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/125403/samsung-rf266-refrigerator-not-cooling-fan-making-noise) I completely defrosted the refrigerator. The issue went away for a few days, but re-surfaced again. So I decided to disassemble to refrigerator understand the root cause of the problem. Yes there is Ice build up. Here are some images.

[image: Ice Buildup Image 1]

As you see in the image below. There is a good amount of ice buildup.

[image]

What are any suggestion to try fixing the issue? How can one test to verify if the fan is still working.

Comment: Can you operate the fridge with the covers off after the ice melts?  It should be apparent if the fan is working or slipping on the shaft.

Comment: @JPhi1618, what I observed is when the door is open the fan stops. I know this because when the ice was present the fan noise is present (doors closed) and when the door is opened the fan stops. Do you know how I can force the fan to operate when the door is open?

Comment: If there is not a lever on the door that pushes a physical switch, there is a magnetic reed switch in the door frame somewhere.  A magnet in the right location would make it think the door was closed (you might have to flip the magnet - north/south could make a difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had same issue with my Samsung refrigerator for a while was defrosting the fridge to work but was lucky to find repair kit for this issue and now not icing anymore for over 4 months now so decided upload my recommendation here.
please use link to view the lifesaver kit :)

[Samsung Refrigerator Defrost Booster Kit -Ice Buildup, Noises and cooling issues repair kit, Samsung ice buildup repair kit](https://parts-4u.ca/products/new-samsung-refrigerator-defrost-booster-kit-ice-buildup-noises-repair-kit-samsung-ice-buildup-repair-kit?_pos=2&_sid=e1c2b1cf6&_ss=r)

good luck guys

Comment: Do you have pictures of your installation? Look modifications to heater design.